# Overlapping header inclusions

Tags: c++, class, header, include

I've run into a simple problem that I need some help with.

I basically have two classes [A & B] (one in each .cpp file with their own .h).

```
A.h #includes the contents from B.h

B.h #includes the contents from A.h
```

**I've included a header guard, yet, if I try to declare any pointers or objects of type A or B, I'm getting the following errors:**

> Error 1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'B'
>
> Error 3   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
>
> Error 4   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
>   does not support default-int

Any way around it? The declarations are there - I just don't know why it won't accept it.

Comment: Looks like you have a mistake in one of the headers. We need to see some code.

Comment: Cyclic dependencies like this are a prime sign of a bad design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only require pointers, you only need a forward declaration. Instead of including the headers in each other, simply forward declare the class you need a pointer to. For example, in `A.h`, you should have:

```
class B;
```

And vice versa in `B.h`.

The reason you're currently having problems is because `A.h` has a `B*` in it, so it includes `B.h`, and `B.h` has a `A*`, so it includes `A.h`. However, the include guard prevents the contents of `A.h` being included again, so `B` can't compile.

Let's take a simple example. Here's `A.h`:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
#include "B.h"

class A {
  B* b;
};
#endif
```

Here's `B.h`:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
#include "A.h"

class B {
  A* a;
};
#endif
```

So let's say we're compiling `A.h`. First we check the inclusion guard, which passes. Then we include `B.h`, which also has an inclusion guard that passes, so lets show that inclusion:

```
#include "A.h"

class B {
  A* a;
};

class A {
  B* b;
};
```

Now this `B.h` includes `A.h`, but the include guard in `A.h` won't pass again, so the include brings nothing in. Our final preprocessed file looks like:

```
class B {
  A* a;
};

class A {
  B* b;
};
```

Now look at the definition of `B`. It has an `A*` in it, but `A` hasn't yet been declared. This gives you an error.

Comment: Oh! This fixed it. Thank you so much, do you mind pointing me to some material that explains why I have to do this? Once again thank you.

Comment: @AndyCarter I tried to give an explanation in my answer. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Ahh, that makes a lot of sense now. Thank you - I really appreciate it.